# How to count value in array with exception?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an array that having integer value

```
Dim array1() As Integer = New Integer() {14,12,0,4,25,0}
```

I would like to count the number of elements that are not zero. The result would be `4` in the array above.

Comment: Loop through each index and check the value if not zero add it to a variable... Also it seems u haven't tried anything. Please update the question where u are stuck and what u have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `Lambda Expression` and `.FindAll`:

```
    Dim array1() As Integer = New Integer() {14, 12, 0, 4, 25, 0}
    Dim matchedItems() As Integer = Array.FindAll(array1, _
                                        Function(x) x > 0)
    MsgBox(matchedItems.Count)
```

It will *find* all items within the array where the item is > 0.

Comment: Answering a question in which the OP clearly hasn't tried an attempt doesn't help them... It doesn't make them try...

Answer (score -1):

Create an integer counter.
Loop over the array and if the value of the index is non-zero, add it to the counter.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Count` method with a predicate that includes only non-zero values.

```
Dim array1() As Integer = New Integer() {14, 12, 0, 4, 25, 0}
Dim nonZero As Integer = array1.Count(Function(i) i <> 0)
```

This counts all members of the array that have values not equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much